# How can i add new key and value in a existing list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a blind auction. So basically it will ask for your name and then your bid. After that, it will ask if there are any bidders, if yes it will ask you the name and the bid price. But after you said yes the terminal will be cleaned. So that the other bidder can't see how much the other person bid, if I run print on the [data_base] it can't print more than two keys and value.

Here is the output:

```
What is your name?: Gael
What is your bid: $560
Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes or 'no'.
yes

\[({'Gael': \['560'\]},)\]
What is your name?: Mikey
What is your bid: $350
Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes or 'no'.
yes

\[({'Mikey': \['350'\]},)\]
What is your name?: Josh
What is your bid: $298
Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes or 'no'.
no
```

Here is the final output:
[({'Mikey': ['350']},), ({'Josh': ['298']},)]

Gael's name and his bid are missing.

Here is the code:

```
import os

while True:
name = input("What is your name?: ")
bid = input("What is your bid: $")

    other_user = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes or 'no'.\n")
    
    if other_user == 'yes':
         os.system('cls')
         data_base = [
    
             ]
    def new_user(name, bid):
        brandnew_user = {
            name: [bid]
            
            },
        
        data_base.append(brandnew_user)
        
    new_user(name, bid)
    print(data_base)
    
    
    if other_user == 'no':
        break
```

Thank you!!

I was expecting that Gael's name and bid will be recorded. But it did not, it only recorded, Mikey and Josh.

Comment: You are clearing out `data_base` in every loop.  You should initialize it OUTSIDE of the loop, not inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better way to organize things.  Also, I'm not sure why you are creating a list of tuples of dictionaries.  Why not just make `data_base` a dictionary and store the new entries as keys?

```
import os

data_base = []
while True:
    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    bid = input("What is your bid: $")

    data_base.append( {name: [bid]} )
    print(data_base)

    other_user = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes or 'no'.\n")
    if other_user == 'no':
        break
```

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
import os

data_base = {}
while True:
    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    bid = input("What is your bid: $")

    data_base[name] = [bid]
    print(data_base)

    other_user = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes or 'no'.\n")
    if other_user == 'no':
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just randomly trying new things that I learned.